# How can I convert a character to a integer in Python, and viceversa?

Tags: python, integer, char, type-conversion

I want to get, given a character, its `ASCII` value.

For example, for the character `a`, I want to get `97`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 720, accepted):

Use [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> ord('a')
97
```

Answer (score 149):

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

Comment: You posted this answer 1 minute before the other guy yet still missed out on the 500+ upvotes...

Comment: that is because the latter got selected as the answer lol

Comment: Such is life. I upvoted this one as well, but I doubt he still cares 11 years later.

Comment: the latter one has documentation links)

Answer (score 22):

ord and chr

Comment: My favorite part about this answer is that they inadvertently wrote a valid line of Python.

Comment: `print ((ord and chr)(0O041))`

Answer (score 4):

Not OP's question, but given the title `How can I convert a character to a integer in Python`,

```
int(num) <==> ord(num) - ord('0')

str(char) <==> ord(char) - ord('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

For long string you could use this.

```
 ''.join(map(str, map(ord, 'pantente')))
```