# How to add an integer to each element in a list?

Tags: python, loops, addition

If I have `list=[1,2,3]` and I want to add `1` to each element to get the output `[2,3,4]`,
how would I do that?

I assume I would use a for loop but not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 239):

```
new_list = [x+1 for x in my_list]
```

Comment: This talk explains it: Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: @DaniSpringer Because you are not assigning to a list.  It's the same as doing `lst = [1, 2, 3]; e = lst[0]; e += 1`. `e` doesn't have any information about where it came from, it's just a variable to which an element of a list have been assigned. After assigning something else to it, the list `lst` won't change.

Comment: and the correspondent lazy computed one:
`new_list = (x+1 for x in my_list)`

Comment: `for i,j in enumerate(list1): list1[i] += 1` works. I'm sure Eduardo's lazy generator is fastest (use `next(list1)` to print)

Comment: thanks. but what if i have tuples in my list like: [(2, 2), (4, 8), (7, 3)]. i want to add all values in the tuples.

Answer (score 35):

The other answers on list comprehension are probably the best bet for simple addition, but if you have a more complex function that you needed to apply to all the elements then [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) may be a good fit.

In your example it would be:

```
>>> map(lambda x:x+1, [1,2,3])
[2,3,4]
```

Comment: `map(1 .__add__, ...)` works too. Note that you need a space between `1` and `.` to prevent the parser thinking it is a float

Comment: I ended up encapsulating it with a list "container" to get rid of the map object
`list(map(lambda x:x+1, [1,2,3]))`

Comment: `map(lambda x:x+1, [1,2,3])` contains a map object not a list.  Have you actually printed it?

Answer (score 30):

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> [x+1 for x in mylist]
[2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

[list-comprehensions python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 20):

if you want to use numpy there is another method as follows

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3]
list1 = list(np.asarray(list1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 16):

Edit: this isn't in-place

Firstly don't use the word 'list' for your variable. It shadows the keyword `list`.

The best way is to do it in place using splicing, note the `[:]` denotes a splice:

```
>>> _list=[1,2,3]
>>> _list[:]=[i+1 for i in _list]
>>> _list
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This is good for changing the existing list, but it still produces a new one.  Is it somehow unsafe to use a generator to avoid the unneeded list creation?  I.e., `_list[:]=(i+1 for i in _list)`.

Comment: that still creates a new list, not possible to do it inplace without a for loop i don't think

Comment: Why do you think `_list[:]=(i+1 for i in _list)` creates a new list?

Comment: I mean, it's in place, but temporarily it will create a whole new list for the rhs.

See these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948293/python-slice-assignment-memory-usage

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877212/python-slice-assignment-of-generator-to-list

Comment: I see what you mean. Calling the temporary sequence a list confused me. Do we actually know anything about its type? Wouldn't that be implementation specific?

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> [x.__add__(1) for x in [1, 3, 5]]
3: [2, 4, 6]
```

My intention here is to expose if the item in the list is an integer it supports various built-in functions.

Answer (score 8):

Python 2+:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> map(lambda x: x + 1, mylist)
[2, 3, 4]
```

Python 3+:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x + 1, mylist))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import numpy as np

np.add([1, 2, 3], 1).tolist()
```

which gives

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone was looking for a solution that only uses built-ins and no `lambda`s:

```py
from functools import partial
from operator import add


my_list = range(1, 4)  # list(my_list) #=> [1, 2, 3]
my_list_plus_one = list(map(partial(add, 1), my_list)  #=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the fastest solution according to my timeit measurements!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for index in range(len(list)):
      list[index] = list[index] +1

print(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across a not so efficient, but unique way of doing it. So sharing it across.And yes it requires extra space for another list.

```
from operator import add
test_list1 = [4, 5, 6, 2, 10]
test_list2 = [1] * len(test_list1)

res_list = list(map(add, test_list1, test_list2))

print(test_list1)
print(test_list2)
print(res_list)

#### Output ####
[4, 5, 6, 2, 10]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[5, 6, 7, 3, 11]
```

Comment: where does "add" come from?

Comment: add should import from operators, `from operator import add`

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers above are very good. I've also seen some weird answers that will do the job. Also, the last answer seen was through a normal loop. This willingness to give answers leads me to `itertools` and `numpy`, which will do the same job in a different way.

Here I present different ways to do the job, not answered above.

```py
import operator
import itertools

x = [3, 5, 6, 7]

integer = 89

"""
Want more vairaint can also use zip_longest from itertools instead just zip
"""
#lazy eval
a = itertools.starmap(operator.add, zip(x, [89] * len(x))) # this is not subscriptable but iterable
print(a)
for i in a:
  print(i, end = ",")


# prepared list
a = list(itertools.starmap(operator.add, zip(x, [89] * len(x)))) # this returns list
print(a)



# With numpy (before this, install numpy if not present with `pip install numpy`)
import numpy

res = numpy.ones(len(x), dtype=int) * integer + x # it returns numpy array
res = numpy.array(x) + integer # you can also use this, infact there are many ways to play around
print(res)
print(res.shape) # prints structure of array, i.e. shape

# if you specifically want a list, then use tolist

res_list = res.tolist()
print(res_list)
```

**Output**

```
>>> <itertools.starmap object at 0x0000028793490AF0> # output by lazy val
>>> 92,94,95,96,                                     # output of iterating above starmap object
>>> [92, 94, 95, 96]                                 # output obtained by casting to list
>>>                   __
>>> # |\ | |  | |\/| |__| \ /
>>> # | \| |__| |  | |     |
>>> [92 94 95 96]                                    # this is numpy.ndarray object
>>> (4,)                                             # shape of array
>>> [92, 94, 95, 96]                                 # this is a list object (doesn't have a shape)
```

My **sole** reason to highlight the use of `numpy` is that one should always do such manipulations with libraries like numpy because it is performance efficient for very large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good solutions, here is some benchmarking.

```py
from functools import partial
from operator import add

test_list = list(range(1000)); n = 3;

%timeit _=list(map(lambda x:x+n, test_list))
%timeit _=[x+n for x in test_list]
%timeit _=[x.__add__(n) for x in test_list]
%timeit _=list(map(lambda x:x.__add__(n), test_list))
%timeit _=list(map(partial(add,n), test_list))

Out:
>> 53.6 µs ± 651 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>> 38.2 µs ± 392 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>> 80.2 µs ± 851 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>> 108 µs ± 513 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>> 53.7 µs ± 332 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Seems like `[x+n for x in test_list]` is the fastest solution in pure python.