# How to add number to all integers in list (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
a = [5,7,11,2,6,8]
print('Toplanılanlar: pleyer , telefon, hiroskuter, it, kompüter, 3d-printer')
print(a)
print('Bütün toplanılan neçə manat artdı?')
manat = input()
for i in range(6): 
  #i need smthng to add here  
print('Toplanılanların yenilənmiş siyahısı:')
print(a)
```

Comment: what is your question exactlt?

Comment: I find it unlikely that you are using both python 2 and python 3. Why tag it with both?

Comment: manat = input();
print(list(map(lambda a: a+manat, a)));
print('Toplanılanların yenilənmiş siyahısı:');

Add this to your code

Comment: a = [5,7,11,2,6,8]
print('Toplanılanlar: pleyer , telefon, hiroskuter, it, kompüter, 3d-printer')
print(a)
print('Bütün toplanılan neçə manat artdı?')
manat = input(); print(list(map(lambda a: a+manat, a)));
print('Toplanılanların yenilənmiş siyahısı:');
manat = int(input())
new_lst = [item + manat for item in a]

Comment: [0:0] unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: exact question is that i need to add a number that i want to all integers in list

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61558294/edit) the question with an explanation of the problem you're experiencing and the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're looking for

```
manat = int(input())
for i in len(a):
    a[i] += manat
```

Or form a new list:

```
manat = int(input())
new_lst = [item + manat for item in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to add an *int* to each element of your list, you can probably find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304408/how-to-add-an-integer-to-each-element-in-a-list). Anyways, try something like:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += manat
```

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood your question, your answer is something like this:

```
a = [5, 7, 11, 2, 6, 8]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += 1
```

so the result will be:

```
a = [6, 8, 12, 3, 7, 9]
```

Comment: but if i want to add a number not in code but in program what is then?

Comment: there are lots of methods to get a list of numbers, for example, use:
my_list = input('enter a list of numbers with space between them').split(' ')

Answer (score 0):

With your prompts written in Azerbaijani, it's not obvious what you are trying to do (at least not for us people who don't speak that language).

In all cases, it is not necessary to loop on a range.

If you are prompting the user for a single number that will increase all counts by the same amount:

```
a = [ c + int(manat) for c in a ]
```

If you are prompting the user for a list of 6 increments applying to each count respectively:

```
a = [ c + int(i) for c,i in zip(a,manat.split()) ]
```