# How do I add a number to every single element in python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop

How do I add a number in my element?

lets say I want to add 10 to every single element in my array

I want my input to be [1,2,3,4,5]
and my output to be [11,12,13,14,15]

This is what I came up with so far

```
def func(z):
        numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4,5]
        num = 10

    
        for i in z:
            numbers.append(i + num)
            i = numbers[-2:]
            return i
```

This prints 5,20 instead of 14 and 15.

Comment: what is `z`? You also returning from loop in first iteration... simple `numbers = [n+10 for n in numbers]` is enough

Comment: A better duplicate: [How to add an integer to each element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9304408/7851470)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a fast, compact way of getting the answer that you want. It's a useful tool for you to learn to write better Python.

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def add_num_to_each(num, number_list)
    return [ii + num for ii in number_list]

print(add_num_to_each(10, number_list))
>>> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single line with map,

```
output_list = list(map(lambda x: x + 10, numbers))
```

Here 'numbers' is your input list.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4,5]

result = [item+10 for item in numbers]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(arr+10)
```

Using `numpy` Library is the smart choice as it reduce the time required to do vector calculation as compared to the iteration through loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can use maps.

```
def addTen(n):
    return n+10

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = map(addTen, numbers)
print(list(result))
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/