# Converting string to number in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file in .ktx format. I have opened the file in 'rb' mode. I want to modify particular bytes in that file. I am reading bytes using read(4) [ i want to read number which is of 4 bytes],  call and convert each chunk into a number. What I want is, to increase that number by specific number and insert it back into file stream. Is there any function in python which converts a byte string to an integer? I tried with int() but it prints some binary data.

my code:

```
bytes=file.read(4)
for char in bytes:
    print hex(ord(char))
```

Comment: are you talking about binary string or what kind of string?

Comment: Has the question been clarified now? I'd like to post an extended answer but cannot at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bytes = file.read(4)
bytesAsInt = struct.unpack("l",bytes)
do_something_with_int(bytesAsInt)
```

I think might be what you are looking for ... its hard to tell from the question though

here is the docs on the struct module https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: `struct` is definitely the way to go, you can even read from the file stream directly.

Comment: how can I write back that into file?

Comment: with `struct.pack` ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

[How can I convert a character to a integer in Python, and viceversa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704152/how-can-i-convert-a-character-to-a-integer-in-python-and-viceversa)

Here is a suggested workflow for what you seem to be wanting to do

- Read the data
- Convert the data to integer
- Add X to the integer, where X is the value you want to increase by

Comment: The OP is dealing with packed binary data, not python `int`s.

Comment: Bytes are characters no matter which language you are programming in, failing to see how converting a char to a corresponding numeric value is not applicable.

Comment: In his own example, he is iterating one char at a time. so this fits with his actual work so far.

Comment: He is iterating one char at a time *incorrectly*, so posting another incorrect answer that follows his method is not useful.

Comment: You state that he is incorrectly doing this, but at the same time voted to close cause of ambiguity, while downvoting all answers here. You are an asset to the community.