# Converting character to int and vice versa in Python

Tags: python, string, encoding

I have an external app that appends the length of the packet at the start of the data. Something like the following code:

```
x = "ABCDE"
x_len = len(x)
y = "GHIJK"
y_len = len(y)
test_string = chr(x_len) + x + chr(y_len) + y
#TODO:perform base64 encoding
```

In the client side of the code I need to be able to extract x_len and y_len and read x and y accrodingly.

```
#TODO:perform base64 decoding
x_len = int(test_string[0])
x = test_string[:x_len]
```

I get the following error:
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x05'

I assume the argument of int is in hex so I probbaly need to do some decoding before passing to the int. Can someone give me a pointer as to what function to use from decode or if there is any easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a character to a integer in Python, and viceversa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704152/how-can-i-convert-a-character-to-a-integer-in-python-and-viceversa)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want `ord()`, not `int()`, since `ord()` is the opposite operation from `chr()`.

Note that your code will only work for lengths up to `255` since that is the maximum `chr()` and `ord()` support.

Comment: Thanks! Is ord() available in 2.6?

Answer (score 2):

```
t="ABCDE"

print reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[ord(i) for i in t])

#output 335
```

usage of ord: it is used to convert character to its ascii values ..

in some cases only for alphabets they consider A :1 --- Z:26 in such cases use

`ord('A')-64` results 1 since we know  `ord('A')` is 65

Comment: The alphabet solution is useful. And if they consider A as 0 to Z as 25 you can `- 65` istead.